# Необходимо вывести конкретное число записей из массива в компоненте ReactJS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

В моем компоненте выводятся посты из вордпресса по rest api. Но вот мне необходимо вывести не все посты на страницу, а только 4. Не совсем понимаю как это лучше отсортировать, подскажите пж?!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const BLOG_API = `http://localhost/test-digital/`;

class Posts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = { // инициализируем состояние по-умолчанию
          posts: []
        };
 
      }

      componentWillMount () {
        return fetch(BLOG_API + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts') // делаем запрос к Wordpress API
        .then((response) => response.json()) // получаем ответ в формате json
        .then(posts => {
          this.setState({
            posts: posts, // обновляем состояние страницы
          });
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ul> 
              {
                this.state.posts.map(item => (
                  <li key={item.id}>
                    <Link to={`/test-digital/${item.id}`}>
                        {item.title.rendered}
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                ))
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

export default Posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'` используйте `'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/per_page=4'`.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Мне это помогло!

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Используй `Array.prototype.slice()`

```
componentWillMount () {
    return fetch(BLOG_API + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts') // делаем запрос к Wordpress API
    .then((response) => response.json()) // получаем ответ в формате json
    .then(posts => {
      this.setState({
        posts: posts.slice(3), // обновляем состояние страницы
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: Да, спасибо! Это действительно работает)

Comment: Был рал помочь)

Comment: Так же, если ты хочешь сохранить полное количество постов, то делай не в componentWillMount (), а непосредственно во время рендера: this.state.posts..slice(3).map(item => (

Comment: И вытащить сразу 20 постов одним запросом (это число по умолчанию в REST). Зачем тащить лишнюю информацию?